# How to prevent pagebreak in quote environment?

Tags: page-breaking, quoting

```
\begin{quote}
``No matter how far apart the particles are when we try to collect one of them the relative probabilities of finding it in different places are strongly affected by the `interference term' in the cross-section it is not really `free' \dots "
\end{quote}
```

How to prevent a page-break occurring mid-quote in the above sample?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) You can put this inside a `minipage` (`\begin{minipage}`...`\end{minipage}`) which is an unbreakable block of objects.

Comment: Put the quote into a samepage environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `\interlinepenalty=10000` in the `quote` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textheight}{10\baselineskip} % Just for the example

\newenvironment{nbquote}
 {\quote\interlinepenalty=10000 }
 {\endquote}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{nbquote}
``No matter how far apart the particles are when we try to collect
one of them the relative probabilities of finding it in different
places are strongly affected by the `interference term' in the
cross-section it is not really `free' \dots''
\end{nbquote}
\end{document}
```

Don't use `"` for the closing quotes, but a pair of apostrophes `''`

[image]

This would be the result with the original `quote` environment

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can put this inside a `minipage` which is an unbreakable block of objects.

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{quote}
``No matter how far apart the particles are when we try to collect one of them the relative probabilities of finding it in different places are strongly affected by the `interference term' in the cross-section it is not really `free' \dots "
\end{quote}
\end{minipage}
```