# memoir - Redefine quote environment to avoid splitting on page breaks

Tags: pdftex, miktex, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class and need to ensure that the quote environment does not split across pages.
In one of my usages of the environment, it has two lines, where the first one is at the bottom of a page and the second one is at the beginning of the next page.

I looked around and saw [a thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140300/how-to-prevent-pagebreak-in-quote-environment) stating that setting `\interlinepenalty` directly in an environment could do the trick:

```
\newenvironment{nbquote}
 {\quote\interlinepenalty=10000 }
 {\endquote}
```

However, I wish to redefine the `quote` environment instead of creating a new one.
I am unsure how to properly redefine it.
In the `memoir.dtx` file, the environment is defined as such:

```
\newenvironment{quote}%
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item[]}%
               {\endlist}
```

I've been trying the following right before `\begin{document}` on the document I'm writing:

```
\renewenvironment{quote}%
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item[]}%
               {\endlist}
               {\quote\interlinepenalty=10000}{\endquote}
```

This produces the following error when compiling:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.51                {\quote
                           \interlinepenalty=10000}
```

I'm not convinced the right approach is to place the code right after `\begin{document}`, but if I do, this is the result:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59                {\endquote
                              }
?
```

I am not sure how to further debug.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The error message you report does not agree with the code you show: the former has a `{` before `\item[]` that is absent in the latter.

Comment: You are right, old copy-paste. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `\interlinepenalty=10000` in your OP was applied in the incorrect spot. The syntax of `\renewenvironment` is

```
\renewenvironment{<environment name>}%
  {stuff to expand from \<environment name>}%
  {stuff to expand from \end<environment name>}
```

**Edit**: The `\interlinepenalty` is one of many parameters that TeX uses in its page-breaking algorithm. Perhaps, in your example, a better command to use is `\samepage`, which is provided by LaTeX. The `\samepage` command sets `\interlinepenalty` to be `10000`, but also sets other related parameters to truly suppress page-break. So let us apply <del>`\interlinepenalty=10000`</del> `\samepage` right after `\item[]`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewenvironment{quote}%
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item[]\samepage}% <- The effect of \samepage is local!!!
               {\endlist}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\begin{quote}
\blindtext[2]
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

The effect of `\samepage` is local in this MWE. However, it is worth pointing out that in the above MWE I have used an unreasonably long text in the `quote` environment. A good practice is that short quote goes into `quote` while long quote goes into `quotation`.

Comment: This did the trick. I wonder what was the idea behind the code snippet in the thread that I link to in my original post.

Comment: @Blitzkoder it is exactly the same thing. I don't see the confusion. Egreg defines a new env, and places the `\interlinepenalty` at the end of the begin part of the env.

Comment: @Blitzkoder I added some explanations and comments to my answer. I also changed `\interlinepenalty=10000` to `\samepage` to encourage the use of LaTeX commands.

Comment: @RuixiZhang For my opinion you have done a good work. +1

Comment: @RuixiZhang I just tried with `\samepage`, which also worked. A neat solution, without polluting the rest of the document structure.